# When and how to remove DataFrame from cache in spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Just learning spark, and I wonder if I during spark script I should clean dataframes after I'm executing a code that runs the DF?

e.g,

```
# Do something on friends DF...
friendsByAge = lines.select("age", "friends")
friendsByAge.groupBy("age").avg("friends").show()

# now do something unrelated to friends DF
```

In the case above, is `friendsByAge` DF is kept in memory during the entire driver script execution (even after I don't need it anymore) and if it does, should I clean it somehow, or once I `show` it it's removed from memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFrame is being loaded lazily, so it's only loaded when you run the action `show`. Also, it won't be cached automatically (only if you explicitly `cache` or `persist` it), so you don't need to worry about cleaning it. If you do cache a DataFrame called `df`, you can remove it from cache using:

```
df.unpersist()
```